TypeError when resuming training with HuggingFace Transformers: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
I'm resuming a training run using the HuggingFace Transformers Trainer. My dataset includes 90M samples, and the previous run crashed after ~1.2M samples (~1.3% through a single epoch). When I try to resume training, I receive the following error message:
 File "/train_transformer/train_gpt_lm.py", line 204, in <module>
    main()
  File "/train_transformer/train_gpt_lm.py", line 191, in main
    trainer.train(resume_from_checkpoint=False)
  File "/my-envs/chess/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1537, in train
    return inner_training_loop(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/my-envs/chess/lib/python3.11/site-packages/accelerate/utils/memory.py", line 136, in decorator
    return function(batch_size, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/my-envs/chess/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line 1793, in _inner_training_loop
    for epoch in range(epochs_trained, num_train_epochs):
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I receive this error both when resume_from_checkpoint=False and resume_from_checkpoint=True. The total number of training epochs (10) is specified via CLI using the HfArgumentParser which is a wrapper around argparse.
Since the num_train_epochs is specified via CLI as 10 (an integer), I think the issue is with epochs_trained, but that's computed by the HF Trainer.
There's an open issue at HuggingFace's github, but I still need a workaround.

One of epochs_trained, num_train_epochs is a float, can you debug which one?
